# SQL Server IPConfig Media Disconnected

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the IP address of my SQL server and when I type in ipconfig into CMD this comes out.

Why is the media disconnected, and how do I connect it?

Using SQL Server Configuration Manager Express 2014

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Comment: Umm. coz LAN wire is not connected your system?

Comment: Where is your sql server hosted?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I knew that was missing lol. I just new put that in. Sorry! Anyways, it is in SQL Server Configuration Manager Express 2014

Comment: Where is the SQL server running? is it on some different system?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Same system and it is running

Comment: then you can use local IP - 127.0.0.1

Comment: But I want to make this program so others can log in as well.

Comment: Then, connect yourself to the network on which the other will connect to you. Then find IP on that adapter using the same method you did before.

Comment: How would I exactly connect myself to the network?